# Jquery/Ajax Variable not defined

Tags: jquery, ajax

When i'm tryng to click the button i'm ghetting an error : popup is not defined , i have no ideea what to do

```
<input href="#dialog" type='button' value='Open' onclick="popup(<?php echo $image['image_id']; ?>); return false;" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function popup(image_id){
                $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'popup.php',
                    data: 'image_id=' + encodeURIComponent(image_id),
                    success: function(data) { 
                        }
                });
            }
</script>
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978944/jquery-variable-not-defined

Comment: What's the image id?  If it's a string you need to wrap it in quotes, but other than that it's fine.  I just ran it and got no errors, so there must be something else causing the problem.

Comment: Pff think is coze of my internet lagging // Duplicate deleted

Comment: image_id is an php id from database

Comment: Please post how your final rendered HTML page looks like.

Comment: What do u mean by final rendered htlm ? source from browser ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Browse the source of the HTML page in your browser and show it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `href` attribute of this `input` element? If not then you don't need that. Also I would suggest you to attach the `click` handler using `jQuery`. But if your markup and server side code does not help then you can try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function popup(image_id){
                $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'popup.php',
                    data: 'image_id=' + encodeURIComponent(image_id),
                    success: function(data) { 
                        }
                });
                return false;
            }
</script>

<input href="#dialog" type='button' value='Open' onclick="return popup('<?php echo $image['image_id']; ?>');" />
```

Comment: And yes i'm using the href atribute to open a popup and return the result of ajax in the popup

Comment: Did you try my edited answer? Try putting the script before the markup.

Comment: Yes same error, i tryed adding click function and document rdy function but same thing

Comment: Yes just the same order as in my main post

Comment: You must be having js error on the page because of which `popup` function is not parsed by JS engine. Take a look in the console if you see any errors.

Comment: Ok ofc me beeing a newb forgot i was already in a ajax loaded page. For example http://domain/ro/index.php#portofolio   if i go like this http://domain/ro/portofolio.php  works but i need it to work in the ajax request

Comment: Basicaly what i'm doing is swiching the contend of the main div with the content from another php file

Comment: Ok, and it contains `popup` function?

Comment: No, so the first i load the content of the portofolio in the wrapper div then i'm tryng to send the popup id to a new php file to call it back and load the image in the popup

Comment: Something from jQuery API docs. When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If .load() is however called with a selector expression appended to the URL, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, which is why they are never executed. An example of both cases can be seen below:

Comment: Its a jQuery limitation to execute the script blocks when `load` is called with a selector expression appended to the url. So you have to keep that function on the parent page to make it work.